# Preact equivalent to renderToNodeStream

Tags: preact

Am looking into switching from React to Preact to understand what the performance improvements could be.

At the moment my application takes advantage of React's `renderToNodeStream` to allow for quicker rendering, but I can't seem to find any equivalent in Preact, or whether preact even supports streaming.

Is anyone aware of whether it does? Or if there's an alternative to use?

Answer (score 2):

Preact does not currently have a stream renderer, but this topic is being tracked as a feature request on GitHub at [preactjs/preact-render-to-string#210](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-render-to-string/issues/210).